# Python Game Development - Update Glut Window while Programming - Like Livereload

Tags: python

I decided to go about learning OpenGL and found some simple examples creating circles and triangles and other colorful weird shapes... But a killer for the development process is closing - xkilling the window and rerunning the file... Is there some faster way to see that GLUT window contents update?

Answer (score 0):

After all i ended up using Pyglet.

Created a basic "Hello World"

```
import pyglet

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_size(800, 600)

    def on_draw(self):

        self.clear()

        label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, World',
            font_name='Arial',
            font_size=36,
            x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
            anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

        label.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

I created a **sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "run pyglet"
pkill -f game.py #kill any game already running
python3 /locationof/game.py
```

I made it executable:

```
chmod +x game.sh
```

or if its kinky

```
cp -R "file to be executable" "/usr/bin" && chmod 755 "/usr/bin/file to be executable"
```

Created a build system for Sublime /Tools/Build System/New Build System:

```
{
"cmd": ["game.sh", "$file_base_name"],
"selector": "source.python",
"file_regex": "file \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]+)"
}
```

And now every time I press Ctrl+B 
Sublime Builds, kills the game and reruns it.